# How to build /dist in an unpublished version of an npm module?

Tags: node.js, git, typescript, npm

Working on a pull request for this module: https://github.com/echoulen/react-pull-to-refresh ...

I believe the published module builds `/dist` in the package.json `prepublish` npm script. I am using the module locally with my github branch installed via `yarn add https://github.com/jbeuckm/react-pull-to-refresh`.

The problem is when I try to build my (consuming) project in a bitbucket pipeline. The pipeline fails when the `react-js-pull-to-refresh` module can not be resolved. I suspect this is because the `/dist` folder is built in `prepublish` and my version is not published.

How can I tell npm to build `/dist` in my unpublished repo module when building the consuming project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `prepublish` script in your `package.json` to `prepare` instead. The `prepare` script should run on the consuming project when installing the dependency.

According to the docs (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install under the bullet-point `npm install <git remote url>`):

> If the package being installed contains a `prepare` script, its dependencies and devDependencies will be installed, and the prepare script will be run, before the package is packaged and installed.

Check out https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#prepublish-and-prepare